# node.js : Nested function style code is harmful than ES6 class style?

Tags: javascript, node.js

(Please excuse my English)

Below is a very simplified example code.

```js
function test(limit) {
    let count = 0, undone = true;

    function inc() {
        // do something
        count++;
        if(count == limit)
            undone = false;
    }

    while(undone) {
        // do something
        inc();
    }
}
```

I'm using nested function style functions very often, like `inc()` in the above example. Because it is very convenient to share variables.
However, someone told me that my coding style is very harmful. Because everytime `test()` (in the above example) is called, the `inc()` is allocated in memory repeatedly. He advised me to use ES6 class style code instead.

I could not agree with him, but not sure. Is nested function style code really harmful than ES6 class style?

> **Edit**
>
> I performed a simple benchmark for this question, as posted
> below.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530670/7339376
>
> The result is somewhat astonishing to me. I was wrong. My
> adviser is right.
>
> **Edit**
> At first, the title of this post was "Closure style code is...". I I modified it to "Nested function style code is...".

Comment: That's not really a closure so much as a function nested in another. But yes, if you call `test` a lot, your `inc` will be re-defined every time, which isn't that efficient. Find another way, if you can.

Comment: I can't see how "ES6 class style" is relevant to the question - the code in the question has nothing to do with classes

Comment: No. Keep it up. In general prefer the most maintainable style that solves your problem. Closures are the very most essential and fundamental aspect of JavaScript.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: As in `inc` will overwriting the same memory slot over and over again? Or there will be multiple copies of the function everywhere?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Except that nothing in the code there is much of a closure.

Comment: @CertainPerformance true the allocation is unnecessary but it can be removed by introducing even more closures

Comment: @CertainPerformance `inc` is a closure

Comment: @Isaac Who knows where the memory will be allocated, but `inc` will be re-parsed as a new function every time `test` runs. The just-created `inc` will immediately be garbage collected once `test` ends, so it's not like there will be copies remaining afterwards, it's just inefficient.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think you have a very deep misunderstanding of closures. The function `inc()` encloses the variable `count` therefore there exists a closure for the variable `count` in `inc()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance `inc` is literal code, not a string. Thus it will be parsed only once. But it may be recompiled (due to closure resolution). This recompilation can in fact be optimised away depending on how closures are implemented internally. Several functional languages do this. So it may or may not be inefficient

Comment: 1 year later, I still think this fails to satisfy the closure definition as "the inner function still has access to the enclosed variable even after the outer function has popped from the stack". am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

For the example above there is no significant difference in theory between using a closure to maintain a private variable and using a class for the same thing.

Using a closure will allocate a new function object each time the `test` function is called.

Using a class will allocate a new object each time the `test` function is called.

In theory, both allocate memory and both spend time calling a constructor.

There are those who may object to the fact that the function will need to be recompiled each time while a method in a class is compiled only once. Note that the closure can also be optimised to compile only once. So it's only a micro-optimisation issue.

Academically, closures and classes are equivalent. I think we first understood this when Lisp implemented objects and classes as a library using closures without any modification to the language but since then there have been research papers published proving that closures and classes are computationally equivalent - only they have slightly different feature sets.

When it comes to optimisations, the only thing you should do is benchmark your code. If it is good enough then **don't change your code**. Any opinion to the contrary is only religious/political and should be ignored. If you need better performance then profile your code to find the real bottleneck. This may be the bottleneck or it may not. Do not optimise code that is not slowing you down.

At the end of the day write the clearest, most readable code you can.

Comment: Look at Mark's answer. The same code using OOP has much more boilerplate and is in my opinion more indirect to read (you read the mechanism and then have to infer the intent vs just read what you meant to do). But there are people who are more used to OOP that find closures harder to read. So it's up to you. It's more a matter of taste than performance

Comment: Yes, 100% ... well said.

Comment: As you advised, I performed a benchmark as posted below. The result is somewhat astonishing. I was wrong and my adviser is right.

Answer (score 2):

(Please excuse my English)

I just performed a benchmark using my Ubuntu 16.04 machine with `perf` command.The result was quite a surprise to me. I was wrong. My adviser is right.
My simple ES6 class style code is 2~3 times efficient than nested function style equivalent.

Below is `class.js`, ES class style, simple loop code.

```js
class test {
    constructor(limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
        this.count = 0;
        this.undone = true;

        while(this.undone) {
            this.inc();
        }
    }

    inc() {
        this.count++;
        if(this.count == this.limit)
            this.undone = false;
    }
}

for(let i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
    new test(100)
}
```

And the result of `perf stat node class` (performed 3 times).

```
 Performance counter stats for 'node class':

       1055.290800      task-clock (msec)         #    1.002 CPUs utilized          
                28      context-switches          #    0.027 K/sec                  
                 6      cpu-migrations            #    0.006 K/sec                  
             2,554      page-faults               #    0.002 M/sec                  
     2,858,088,136      cycles                    #    2.708 GHz                    
       892,221,452      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   31.22% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
     5,815,629,017      instructions              #    2.03  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.15  stalled cycles per insn
     2,561,547,866      branches                  # 2427.338 M/sec                  
         6,776,303      branch-misses             #    0.26% of all branches        

       1.053429789 seconds time elapsed


 Performance counter stats for 'node class':

       1057.919398      task-clock (msec)         #    1.002 CPUs utilized          
                28      context-switches          #    0.026 K/sec                  
                 6      cpu-migrations            #    0.006 K/sec                  
             2,555      page-faults               #    0.002 M/sec                  
     2,856,736,277      cycles                    #    2.700 GHz                    
       890,790,850      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   31.18% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
     5,815,147,889      instructions              #    2.04  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.15  stalled cycles per insn
     2,561,451,165      branches                  # 2421.216 M/sec                  
         6,778,756      branch-misses             #    0.26% of all branches        

       1.056058390 seconds time elapsed


 Performance counter stats for 'node class':

       1054.245840      task-clock (msec)         #    1.002 CPUs utilized          
                27      context-switches          #    0.026 K/sec                  
                 9      cpu-migrations            #    0.009 K/sec                  
             2,553      page-faults               #    0.002 M/sec                  
     2,856,022,458      cycles                    #    2.709 GHz                    
       890,300,670      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   31.17% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
     5,815,241,984      instructions              #    2.04  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.15  stalled cycles per insn
     2,561,469,424      branches                  # 2429.670 M/sec                  
         6,768,183      branch-misses             #    0.26% of all branches        

       1.052295061 seconds time elapsed
```

Below is `nested.js` (nested function style equivalent to class.js)

```js
function test(limit) {
    let count = 0, undone = true;

    function inc() {
        count++;
        if(count == limit)
            undone = false;
    }

    while(undone) {
        inc();
    }
}

for(let i=0; i<5000000; i++) {
    test(100)
}
```

And the result of `perf stat node nested` (also performed 3 times).

```
 Performance counter stats for 'node nested':

       2377.214932      task-clock (msec)         #    1.002 CPUs utilized          
               389      context-switches          #    0.164 K/sec                  
                 9      cpu-migrations            #    0.004 K/sec                  
             3,141      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
     6,560,657,082      cycles                    #    2.760 GHz                    
     1,946,461,285      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   29.67% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    16,046,574,530      instructions              #    2.45  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.12  stalled cycles per insn
     6,110,865,652      branches                  # 2570.599 M/sec                  
         6,953,209      branch-misses             #    0.11% of all branches        

       2.371426270 seconds time elapsed


 Performance counter stats for 'node nested':

       2381.292759      task-clock (msec)         #    1.002 CPUs utilized          
               391      context-switches          #    0.164 K/sec                  
                 8      cpu-migrations            #    0.003 K/sec                  
             3,142      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
     6,558,376,504      cycles                    #    2.754 GHz                    
     1,943,542,624      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   29.63% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    16,046,969,491      instructions              #    2.45  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.12  stalled cycles per insn
     6,110,955,583      branches                  # 2566.234 M/sec                  
         6,967,852      branch-misses             #    0.11% of all branches        

       2.375578434 seconds time elapsed


 Performance counter stats for 'node nested':

       2376.579401      task-clock (msec)         #    1.003 CPUs utilized          
               388      context-switches          #    0.163 K/sec                  
                 7      cpu-migrations            #    0.003 K/sec                  
             3,125      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
     6,562,861,447      cycles                    #    2.761 GHz                    
     1,947,165,390      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   29.67% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    16,051,805,939      instructions              #    2.45  insns per cycle        
                                                  #    0.12  stalled cycles per insn
     6,111,984,155      branches                  # 2571.757 M/sec                  
         6,962,744      branch-misses             #    0.11% of all branches        

       2.369557403 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common argument against adding functions directly as properties to objects, or by defining them inside other objects. But you don't need ES6 to change this. Plain old function prototypes have been used for a long time for this.

For example in this code, the `inc` function is created once regardless of how many test objects are created.

```js
function test(limit) {
  this.limit = limit
  this.count = 0
  this.undone = true;
}
test.prototype.inc = function() {
  console.log("something", this.count)
  this.count++;
  if (this.count == this.limit)
    this.undone = false;
}

let t = new test(10)
while (t.undone) {
  t.inc()
}
```

You can also do this with plain old object prototypes, which allow you to share the same function with several objects:

```js
const test = {
    limit: undefined,
    count: 0,
    undone: true,
    inc() {
        console.log("something", this.count)
        this.count++;
        if(this.count == this.limit)
            this.undone = false;
    }
}

let t = Object.create(test)
t.limit = 5
while(t.undone) {
    t.inc()
} 

let p = Object.create(test)
p.limit = 5
while(p.undone) {
    p.inc()  // <-- same inc() as t.inc()
}
```